# Strip all attributes from allowed HTML tags when using strip_tags on HTML string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a HTML string, i need to strip all HTML tags & inline styling except `<p>`.

```
var html = '<p style="padding:0px;">Outside<strong style="padding:0;margin:0;">hello</strong></p>';
```

I am using the following javascript function. It works

```
function strip_tags(input, allowed) {
    allowed = (((allowed || "") + "").toLowerCase().match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || []).join(''); // making sure the allowed arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)
    var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
        commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
    return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '').replace(tags, function ($0, $1) {
        return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
    });
}

var striped = strip_tags(html, '<p>');

console.log(striped);
```

The above code outputs

```
<p style="padding:0px;">Outsidehello</p>
```

But I need the attributes of allowed tags also to be striped.

for example, I need output as

```
<p>Outsidehello</p>
```

I tried with several regular expression, but I can't able to get it working.

Some of regexp I tried are

```
var striped = html.replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/gi",'<$1$2>');
var striped = html.replace('/<(\w+)[^>]*>/', '<$1>');
```

Any idea how to strip off all the attributes of allowed HTML tags ?

Comment: By _allowed_ tags, do you mean tags like `<p>` as opposed to `</p>` or `<p/>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `replace()` two times with two different Regular Expressions.

1- Start with:

```
<(?!/?(p))\w*[^<>]*>
```

to strip all other tags.

2- Then continue with:

```
(<p)[^<>]*
```

to strip attributes (if any).

Putting the idea all together into a function:

```
function strip_tags(text, tags) {
    return text.replace(new RegExp("<(?!/?(" + tags.join('|') + "))\\w*[^<>]*>", "gi"), '')
    .replace(new RegExp("(<" + tags.join('|') + ")[^<>]*", "gi"), "$1");
}
```

JS code:

```js
var text = `<p style="padding:0px;">Outside
<td class="comment-text">
   <div style="display: block;" class="comment-body">
      <span class="comment-copy">Do you mean <code>&lt;p&#47;&gt;</code> ?</span>
      &ndash;&nbsp;<a href="/users/557597/sln"
         title="19,684 reputation"
         class="comment-user">sln</a>
   </div>
</td>
</tr>
<strong style="padding:0;margin:0;">hello</strong></p>`;

function strip_tags(text, tags) {
 return text.replace(new RegExp("<(?!/?(" + tags.join('|') + "))\\w*[^<>]*>", "g"), '')
 .replace(new RegExp("(<" + tags.join('|') + ")[^<>]*", "g"), "$1");
}

console.log(strip_tags(text, ['p', 'div']))


var text = '<p style="padding:0px;">Outside <strong style="color:red;">hello</strong></p>';
console.log(strip_tags(text, ['p']))
```

Comment: when allowed multiple tags such as strip_tags(text, [p,div]) it fails. the matching ending tag </div> </p> is also stripped.

Comment: the strip_tags function is taken from here http://locutus.io/php/strings/strip_tags/

Comment: You need to do a `.replace('&nbsp;', '')` within `strip_tags` function.

Comment: It still allows tags inside allowed tags. For ex. It fails in this scenario 
var text = '<p style="padding:0px;">Outside <strong style="color:red;">hello</strong></p>';

console.log(strip_tags(text, ['p']))

Comment: Works Now. Thanks. I am using it for striping out word HTML. Trusting this function for large copy/paste from word.

Comment: It's a promising, bulletproof method.

Comment: The strip_tags function has a bug in the second replace regex. Here is the correct one: function strip_tags(text, tags) { return text.replace(new RegExp("<(?!/?(" + tags.join('|') + "))\\w*[^<>]*>", "g"), '').replace(new RegExp("(<(" + tags.join('|') + "))[^<>]*", "g"), "$1"); }

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe ?

```js
var Rx = new RegExp("<(?:(?:/?([\\w:]+)\\s*/?)|(?:([\\w:]+)(\\s+(?:\"[\\S\\s]*?\"|'[\\S\\s]*?'|[^>]?)+)\\s*/?)|\\?[\\S\\s]*?\\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\\S\\s]*?)|(?:\\[CDATA\\[[\\S\\s]*?\\]\\])|(?:--[\\S\\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\\S\\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\\S\\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\\S\\s]*?))))>", 'g');

var input = '<meta charset="UTF-8" /><title>International English Language Testing System - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</title><meta name="generator" content="MediaWiki 1.25wmf2" /><link rel="alternate" href="android-app://org.wikipedia/http/en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_English_Language_Testing_System" /><link rel="alternate" type="application/x-wiki" title="Edit this page" href="/w/index.php?title=International_English_Language_Testing_System&amp;action=edit" />';

var Allowed = [ 'link' ];  // array
function TestAllowed( tag )
{
   for ( var i = 0; i < Allowed.length; i++ )
      if ( Allowed[i] == tag )
          return true;
   return false;
}

console.log(
  input.replace(
      Rx,
      function( m, p1, p2, p3 )
      {
         if ( p1 )
         {
            if ( TestAllowed( p1 ) )
                return m;
         }
         else
         if ( p2 )
         {
            if ( TestAllowed( p2 ) )
            {
               p3 = p3.replace(/^[\S\s]*?(\/?)$/, "$1");
               return '<' + p2 + p3 + '>';
            }
         }
         return '';
      
      } ));
```